# $N(T) \subset N(S \circ T)$ and $R(S\circ T) \subset R(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V \longrightarrow W$ and $S : W \longrightarrow Z$ be linear maps.

I need some help proving that

(i) $N(T) \subset N(S  \circ T)$

and

(ii) $R(S\circ T) \subset R(S).$

Comment: $x \in N(S\circ T) \implies S(T(x))=0$, but this means $T(x)\in W$. What does this show?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in V,~ x\in N(T)$ so $T(x)=0_W$ and therefore $S(T(x))=S(0_W)=0_Z$ and then $x\in N(S\circ T)$.

Comment: So would (ii) wind out like this: $x\in R(S\circ T) \implies x =S(T(v))$ for some $v\in V$, but then $x\in R(S)$.

Comment: @AetiusBarlaam: It seems right. Note that we assume here that the composition of T by S is allowed.

Comment: Very nicely done, Babak! +1